# How to draw a circle layer on a scatter chart using Echarts

Tags: echarts

How to draw something like the below screenshot in Echarts?

[image]

With ECharts, I can easily draw scatter and axes, include zooming and panning features. However, when I need to draw a new layer on top of scatter, things getting messy. I tried using custom series of e-chart, however, its api and documentation is hard to understand, Besides, its zooming function works weird on multiple series.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the circle by adding a customized data item to your scatter series.

Here's a sample option:

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        max: 12
    },
    yAxis: {
        max: 12
    },
    series: {
        type: 'scatter',
        symbolSize: 20,
        data: [
            [6.0, 8.04],
            [8.0, 6.95],
            [3.5, 8.81],
            [5.0, 8.33],
            [6.0, 7.24],
            [4.0, 4.26],
            [8.0, 7.84],
            [7.0, 4.82],
            [5.0, 5.68],
            {
                value: [6, 6],
                symbolSize: 400,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'rgba(1,1,1,0)',
                    borderColor: '#00f',
                    borderWidth: 4
                }

            }
        ]
    }
};
```

...which should produce this output:
[echarts scatter series with enclosing circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iD1Q.png)

See https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.data and scroll down a bit for more information on customized data items.

Comment: I think this is a hack as you used scatter data with custom size of circle to render the big circle.
I found another way that is use custom series. It works but it's doesn't cooperate well with zooming.

Comment: It's not possible to use this  solution when you have dataZoom.